# wxScrolledWindow not working as expected

Tags: wxwidgets

I have a problem with wxScrolledWindow.

I have a ScrolledWindow holding a wxListBox.

**Behavior that works:**

On adding items to the listbox the scrollbar will eventually appear.

**Behavior that fails:**

wxListBox has some items. When i reduce the size of the ScrolledWindow such that some items are occluded, the scrollbar fails to appear.

```
// split window into 2
wxBoxSizer *sizermain = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
wxSplitterWindow *splittermain = new wxSplitterWindow(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxSP_LIVE_UPDATE);
splittermain->SetSashGravity(0.5);
splittermain->SetMinimumPaneSize(20);
sizermain->Add(splittermain, 1,wxEXPAND,0);
this->SetSizer(sizermain);

// split left window into 2
wxSplitterWindow * splitterleft = new wxSplitterWindow(splittermain, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxSP_LIVE_UPDATE);
splitterleft->SetSashGravity(0.5);
splitterleft->SetMinimumPaneSize(20);
wxBoxSizer * sizerleft = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
sizerleft->Add(splitterleft, 1, wxEXPAND, 0);

// split right window into 2
wxSplitterWindow * splitteright = new wxSplitterWindow(splittermain, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxSP_LIVE_UPDATE);
splitteright->SetSashGravity(0.5);
splitteright->SetMinimumPaneSize(20);
wxBoxSizer * sizerright = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
sizerright->Add(splitteright, 1, wxEXPAND, 0);

wxScrolledWindow *tlpnl = new wxScrolledWindow(splitterleft, wxID_ANY);
wxListBox *tlcalls = new wxListBox(tlpnl, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, nullptr, wxLB_EXTENDED);
wxBoxSizer *tlsizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
tlsizer->Add(tlcalls, 1,wxEXPAND,0);
tlpnl->SetSizer(tlsizer);

wxScrolledWindow *blpnl = new wxScrolledWindow(splitterleft, wxID_ANY);
wxListBox *blcontacts = new wxListBox(blpnl, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, nullptr, wxLB_EXTENDED);
wxBoxSizer *blsizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
blsizer->Add(blcontacts, 1,wxEXPAND,0);
blpnl->SetSizer(blsizer);

wxScrolledWindow *trpnl = new wxScrolledWindow(splitteright, wxID_ANY);
inCall = new wxListBox(trpnl, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0, nullptr, wxLB_EXTENDED);
wxBoxSizer *trsizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
trsizer->Add(inCall, 1,wxEXPAND,0);
trpnl->SetSizer(trsizer);

wxScrolledWindow *brpnl = new wxScrolledWindow(splitteright, wxID_ANY);
wxTextCtrl *brtext = new wxTextCtrl(brpnl, wxID_ANY);
wxBoxSizer *brsizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
brsizer->Add(brtext, 1,wxEXPAND,0);
brpnl->SetSizer(brsizer);

splittermain->SplitVertically(splitterleft, splitteright);
splitterleft->SplitHorizontally(tlpnl, blpnl);
splitteright->SplitHorizontally(trpnl, brpnl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem to show the problem (as there are no items anywhere) but there is at least one thing wrong with it: you create `sizerLeft` and `sizerRight` sizers and add something to them but never use these sizers themselves. This might explain the layout problems... But if it doesn't, you really should show the code that actually shows the problem you're describing (and perhaps shorter than what you have, are both splitters actually needed?).

Comment: I dont't really understand what you mean by no items anywhere? I have 3 wxSplitterWindow instances splitting the frame into 4 parts. Each part has either a wxListBox or a wxTextCtrl. I am using the sizer objects as per http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxSplitterWindow

Comment: You have no items in any of the listboxes, yet your description of the problem begins with "wxListBox has some items" -- this doesn't match your test code. Also, do look at the sizers I mentioned, they are not set up correctly as you don't add them to any other sizer nor associate with any window, there *is* a problem here, wiki link or not.